# NSPredicate Not Working properly on 64 bit device

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using predicate with below format

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"item LIKE %@", @"itemName"];

NSArray *array = [fetchedObjects filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

But it fail on 64 bit device to filter result array objects which is fetched from core data.

It workes fine on 32 bit devices.

Please help.

Comment: Did you receive any error message?

Comment: No It returns nil in result array. Due to that reason I am also unable to find what is the problem.

Comment: Did you try self.item in predicate?

Comment: Yes I tried. Is there anything wrong in above predicateFormat ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below alternative solutions..

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"item CONTAINS[cd] %@", @"itemName"];

/////(OR)

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"item==%@", @"itemName"];

NSArray *array = [fetchedObjects filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Hope it helps you..!

Comment: I have checked with above format. Still facing issue. When you choose 64 bit simulator, it works. But when you run app on 64 bit device, then it won't works.